# What does the MINGW64 on Git Bash mean?

Tags: c++, mingw, git-bash, mingw-w64

So, I am planning to start learning C++ today, and I prefer using VSCode over other text editors/IDEs, and don't want to use replit.com either.

However, while watching a tutorial, the explainer said that you should download mingw, which caught my eye.  I had already downloaded Git Bash a while ago, and I realized that there's a purple "MINGW64" that appears.  Is this the same thing as what the tutorial was talking about?

This is what it looks like:

[image: Is this Mingw?]

(I am not currently signed into my computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mingw-w64 project is a complete runtime environment for gcc to support binaries native to Windows 64-bit and 32-bit operating systems.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/